# Can you include the values of other variables in the identifiers of new variables in the declaration statement in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, class, variable-declaration

I am trying to create a wysiwyg android layout xml editor. I have a class, button(), which holds all the relavent properties of a button which can be placed on the layout (textcolour, size, position etc.).
When a user clicks a button on the form, a new button is added to the editor view. I want to be able to create a new instance of this class for each button in the layout, so they can be written to the xml file. However, when declaring the instance, I want to be able to name them as button1, button2 etc. Maybe some code would make more sense...:

```
Public Class button 'The class where all the properties for the button are defined
    ...
End Class

Public Partial Class MainForm 'The mainform class
    Dim btnclassno As Integer = 0 'The number of button() classes made
    ...
    Sub btnAddButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        btnclassno += 1 'Changes it by 1
        Dim (newbutton & btnclassno) As button = New button()'Defines a new instance of the class called newbutton and then the value of btnclassno (e.g. newbutton1, newbutton2 etc.)
        ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

I want to know if this is even possible, and if so how to do it, or perhaps even better a more efficient way of making a new instance of the class without having hardcoded names (I am relatively new to the concept of classes so I don't quite understand how to use them).
Thanks.

Comment: This can be done but, I must ask, why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Sub btnAddButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    static btnclassno = 0
    Dim newButton As new Button

    btnclassno += 1 'Changes it by 1

    newButton.Name = "newButton" & trim(str(btnClassno))

    'another newButton properties here 

    Me.Controls.Add(newButton)

    'Dim (newbutton & btnclassno) As button = New button()'Defines a new instance of 

    'class called newbutton and then the value of btnclassno (e.g. newbutton1, newbutton2 etc.)

  End Sub
```

Comment: I get errors: "Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'xml_editor.Button' (on the ctype line) & "Value of type 'xml_editor.Button' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'" (the controls.add)        Could you explain what this code is meant to do, because as far as I know the ctype is converting "newButton1" or whatever into the Button class, which doesn't help. I want to be able to incorporate the value of btnclassno into the identifier of the newButton variable. (Sorry I unvoted because the code didn't actually work.)

Comment: @ matzone Ok the .name bit now works, but I still get the Controls.add error. Doesn't Me.controls only contain objects on the form (interface) of the program? Why would adding the class to that help? I'm sounding really critical now, thanks for trying to help.